# Download multi image using XMLHttpRequest. Request all done, but only get 10 or 20 image

Tags: javascript, ajax, image, download, xmlhttprequest

Hi I am trying to download image from web page.

Run code in devtool and create a booklet for it.
My code is work, but if imgarr.length is bigger, I only get 10 or 20 image. I have check all request, they still work (status 200). Please help me what wrong with this.

```
var imgarr = [url1, url2,...] // using querySelectorAll to get Array of URL Image;
try {
    for (var i = 0; i < imgarr.length; i++) {
        download(imgarr[i],'image')
    };
} catch (e) {
    alert("Download failed.");
    console.log('Download failed.', e);
}

function download(url, fileName) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
            var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.response);
            var a = document.createElement("a");
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.style = "display: none";
            a.href = url;
            a.download = fileName;
            a.click();
            document.body.removeChild(a);
        }
    }
    xhr.send();
}
```

Comment: can you please share the url used in request ? do you want to keep it as anonymus ?

Comment: Why do you download images? It doesn't needed to create links click on them. Additionally, you don't need the `try-catch` because it can't catch async events.

Comment: Im download image from customer images on amazon. The link is usually like this https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61QxXOmyhFL._SL256_.jpg. I think problem is not stack in request.